# How to determine background and object colors in powerpoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, colors

I was just wondering how to determine the color (and gradient) settings of a slides background and various objects (text and auto-shapes)? When I try to change the color of slide, PowerPoint does not give me any information about the current color/gradient settings.

If it is not possible to determine the color value of objects in a slide, can anyone tell me how I might go about duplicating the color settings of various objects on a slide. I suppose I could just copy the shape and text but what if I need to use slides background color? is there a way to determine what the current background color is?

Comment: This is such a bad oversight in the PowerPoint design that it hurts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [**Pixie**](http://www.nattyware.com/pixie.php) for all my color matching needs.

[image]

Comment: was looking for a way to color match within powerpooint but I will try pixie. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same, so frustrating. Here's what I found for finding the background color.

Click on the object in Powerpoint, then choose Format Background from the Slide Background category in the Formatting Palette. Click on the Color dropdown, click on More Colors, the color shown in the bar above the color wheel is the color in the object. Drag and drop it into the bar of chosen colors below the color wheel.

Now you've got your background color!